# Editor for Custom file type like YAML

Tags: validation, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, atom-editor, intellij-plugin

I have created one custom file type. Which will be YAML document but having a particular schema. This document is going to be a huge document, and generating this document is currently quite a pain for users.

I need to ease out the creation of the files for the users. Maybe custom plugin into existing IDEs like IntelliJ idea or Atom might help. This will enable user to

1. Code completion.
2. Syntax Highlighting
3. Adherence to particular to schema

What are the best and quick way to facilitate user with such tools? Any other tools/editors suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As an intellij plugin developer I can say this question is quite specific and valid - no need to close. Thank you.

Comment: Does this plugin help: https://github.com/vermut/intellij-snakeyaml?

Comment: @glitch I'll go through it. But seems like IntelliJ plugin is going to take some time and quite lot of understanding. Maybe I should look for some other options which are quick and easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a plugin for IntelliJ that gives you code highlighting, navigation, search and similar features.

It's quite complicated, so you need to understand:

- intellij platform architecture and subsystems (virtual file system, project, document, events, etc)
- intellij plugin development
- `ant-lr` style code grammar
- AST (code tree)

Here's some links to get started. It is possible, but the last time I did this it took upwards of 200 hours.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugin-development-guidelines.html

https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vikingsteve. I tried the basic tutorial given by JetBrains for the simple file type. But learning curve seems to be quite steep. While you were doing the plugin development, did you come across any other approaches that take less time compared to IntelliJ plugin?

Comment: Not really. It's convenient to use the intellij editor. Im not so familiar with yaml, but isnt there a plugin for it already? Did you try this? I found an inbuilt feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-yaml.html

Comment: Or this? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7792-yaml-ansible-support

Comment: Thing is the custom file resembles to YAML but has its own custom format. So I've no option other than to create custom validation. I've checked that plugin, but it's not exactly the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Right then you have no choice other than to write a plugin, unless you can adjust your own format to conform to "traditional" yaml

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your inputs. I'll give it some thought and decide the approach.